# When using a PowerPoint file located on dropbox, the hyperlink sometimes will give error 'Cannot open the specified file'

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, dropbox, hyperlink

We have a number of PowerPoint files that our users use on Dropbox that have a number of hyperlinks in them that link to PDF files that reside in the same file as the PPT file is.

Most of the time, this works fine.. The user clicks the button that has the hyperlink and the PDF is rendered no problem. But sometimes, especially after editing the PPT (not the hyperlink stuff, but other content in the PPT file), the links no longer work and we get the error message that say 'Cannot open the specified file'.

Our users use dropbox so that it 'replicates' their folders to their hard drives and they launch the PPT files by clicking them via Windows Explorer.. So the 'current folder' should be the folder  that their PPT file is in (I think). But what's odd is when I go to examine the hyperlink when the PPT file on the replicated dropbox folder, it looks odd (as if the current folder is not defined correctly) and sometimes those links will work and sometimes they won't. See Image #1  below.

But if I copy that  folder to place on my hard drive NOT on dropbox and launch it from that folder, looking at the same hyperlink, it looks fine and the 'current folder' is set properly.  See Image #2 below.

So my suspicion is MS-Office and Dropbox just aren't playing nicely together when opening the file from the dropbox.

[Image #1 and #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0liy.png)

Comment: If you edit the file, the automatically changed hyperlink could point back to the full path on DropBox, and their file system structure might differ from yours. If you consistently take the files locally, edit them on the PC, and then return them to DropBox, does everything work consistently?

Comment: First off, thanks for the quick response.. yes, editing the file locally then returning them to dropbox seems to be fine..  It's just because these files are shared files that multiple people need access to and be able to view/edit/use that we have them on dropbox. Also, much of our userbase is not very techy so we're trying to avoid the need to copy files back and forth from dropbox to hard drive, etc. so was hoping for a 'stay editing it on dropbox' solution.

Comment: Posted same query to this forum:  https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Integrations/When-using-a-PowerPoint-file-located-on-dropbox-hyperlink/m-p/702195#M10341